# How to Choose which OpenCV to use in CMakeLists.txt when I have two OpenCV (same versions) in my computer?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

I installed ROS in my computer. And ROS automatically installed opencv 3.2 in my computer. As I need to use functions in opencv's extra modules, I installed opencv again from source.

Now I have a c++ project and I want to use the opencv I installed from source instead of the one that comes with ROS. As both are 3.2 version, I don't know how to select which opencv to use in CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Please indicate how you configured CMake to search for OpenCV.

Comment: I just use `find_package(OpenCV 3.2 QUIET)`, which automatically find the opencv in ROS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indicate where to search for packages by changing parameters to [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html), for example:

```
find_package(OpenCV 3.2 QUIET NO_DEFAULT_PATH PATHS "/path/to/custom/opencv")
```

In this case, CMake will not search for OpenCV in usual locations but will search only in the path you specified.